# Resume other apps programmatically

Tags: android, android-intent, launcher

How to resume **other** app from recent apps tab? For example, if we write a launcher app and we don't want to start every time main activity of the app.

I tried something like that:

```
    PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
    Intent         intent  = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
    if (intent == null) {
        Toast.makeText(context, "app does not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

but it is not working - what flag should I set?

### Solution:

Ok. I just have to change this part:

```
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    context.startActivity(intent);
```

to this:

```
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_REORDER_TO_FRONT);
    context.startActivity(intent);
    context.finishAffinity();
```

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
  Intent launchAppIntent = context.getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName);
             if (launchAppIntent != null) {    
               launchAppIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
               context.startActivity(launchAppIntent);
               finishAffinity();
      }
```

Comment: It opens wanted activity correctly but inside my application (in task manager I can see two similar views - from app A and from my app) I want to go back to this app A

Comment: add finishAffinity(); after startActivity();

Comment: Unfortunately it changes nothing.